# Website Multi Languuage

Tags: php, javascript, html, css3

I have one website and the website are now in HTML, that actually is structured:

```
domain.com = English
domain.com/es = Spanish 
domain.com/de = Germany
```

I copied the HTML of English page to Spanish and Germany and I edit the Text, sometimes when I want add some extra code on English, I need open the Spanish, Germany and also add same code, that is very job, so i want know how i can solve that

Thanks

Comment: close voters : this is a very specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is to know that Multi language/culture stuff is called "Internationalisation and Localisation" or shortened to "i18n"

Once you know that your google searches will start returning helpful results, such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953528/best-way-to-internationalize-simple-php-website

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to separate the *layout* of these pages from their *content*.

I assume that you want the same general appearance for the corresponding pages in all languages. So instead of copying the pages for each language and changing their content:

- create a template page that has some placeholders or variables
- write the content for each language variant so that it provides these variables
- render the actual pages by filling in the placeholders in the template with the content for the correct language.

Many Content Management Systems have plugins that can help with translations and internationalization. If have developed your website from scratch, it's also easy to implement a basic translation system yourself.

The difficulty is that you often don't want to translate every page in every language. So sometimes you will still have to fall back to copying a page and editing it for one language only. But in principle you can freely combine these approaches.